# range extension (movestartwhile and moveendwhile) fail when using zeros at the end of range

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

In MS Word document, I have a number with spaces, e.g. 999 000 000 000 000. As you can see, it includes spaces. The cursor position is at the end of the number. I need to extend the range (move start position) to left to get all number. I am using this function: `rngPrice.MoveStartWhile cset:="0123456789" & ChrW(&H2E) & ChrW(&H2C) & ChrW(&H20), Count:=wdBackward` However, all I get are the last three zeros (000). Why does it not get the full number? How do I fix it? Btw, &H2E is period, &H2C is comma and &H20 is whitespace.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the source of the problem. When typing numbers, MS Word sometimes automatically replaces normal whitespaces with non-breaking spaces. So, all I need to do is to include the non-breaking space ChrW(&HA0) in the cset.

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't expect Word to insert a non-breaking space... *unless* the text is formatted with a language such as French, which will make this kind of insertion before certain kinds of punctuation. Just out of interest, can you give steps for reproducing Word's doing this when typing a number?

Comment: Sure. I typed 777 999 000. I used Times New Roman, Font Size 12. When I pressed the Show Paragraphs button, it showed that the spaces are turned into non-breaking spaces. I did the same with the Show Paragraphs button activated, and noticed that the spaces are replaced with non-breaking spaces the moment you press the spacebar for the second time, i.e. after "999". So, MS Word changes whitespaces to non-breaking spaces when you press the spacebar for the second time when typing numbers.

Comment: Ummm, not on my installation and, as far as I know, not on any default English-language installation in any version of Word. (I can speak for Word 2.0 through 2016/Office 365). There must be something special about your setup. With which language is the text formatted? (You can see that in the bar across the bottom of the Word application.)

Comment: It is English (US). I am using Office 2010.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information. I don't feel right pursuing this any further in comments... I don't see an `AutoFormatAsYouType` option that would covers this - perhaps it's an add-in...

Comment: Strangely, removing the flag from the "Straight quotes with Smart quotes" checkbox in the "Autoformat as you Type" tab solves the problem. I've no idea how this is related to non-breaking spaces. Here is a link where a user discusses the same problem, but it's in russian: http://www.cyberforum.ru/ms-word/thread1545404.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "[!A-Za-z^13^l^t]{1,}"
  .Forward = False
  .Format = False
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .IgnorePunct = True
  .IgnoreSpace = True
  .Execute
End With
```